# cronjob for file transfer on windows

Tags: cron

We're using putty and a ssh connection to our webhost. They backup our files daily onto their servers.

Since the backup files use a large amount of space, we now want to copy the backup files to our own server via a cronjob daily.

How do we have to set up the cronjob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the the backup filepath and `filename` (eg: `backup_ddmmyyyy.tar.gz`), you can simply `scp` that backup file from one server to another.

Put this `scp` command inside a shell script, and configure it accordingly with server address of the other server, and location where you want to copy the file.

Since your backup files use a large amount of space, my guess is, they are large sized individually as well, so using `rsync over ssh` instead of a plain `scp` might be a better option to compensate for network failures.

Once your script is working, you can put in a cronjob for that script for an appropriate time, after the backups on webhost are guaranteed to be over.

Comment: Thank you, I'm gonna try that. In what case exactly would it be a better option to use `rsync over ssh` instead of `scp`? Our backup files contain some larger sized elements but in general it is the mass of pictures etc. that leads to the large file sizes.